# Problem in Opera when sorting by (recent|views|newest|votes) in user profile page

Tags: bug, status-declined, opera

Whenever I click to sort my questions or answers in my user profile page, it goes to the top of the page, and I need to scroll back down to see the questions/answers.

In firefox I observe that when I sort, it automatically scrolls down to the proper location, which isn't happening in Opera.

- Version 10.10 beta
- Build 1729
- Platform Win32
- System Windows Vista Home Premium

Answer (score 2):

I tested and this is still an issue in Opera 10.

Sorry Opera has so many compatibility issues; that same page works in

- Safari 3/4
- Chrome 2.x
- Firefox 2/3
- IE 7/8

Can you file this as a bug against Opera?

(but hey, at least the tag editor works properly now in Opera 10! Maybe sometime in the next seven versions Opera will get the rest of their bugs and compatibility issues fixed.)

Comment: :( Have already filed bug with Opera. Thankfully, it's a minor annoyance at the most.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was already there in 9.64. Nothing new with the 10 release.